# 'jenkins do not perform sendkey() operation'

Tags: jenkins, robotframework, sendkeys

I have sendkeys() function defined in python file which i am calling in robot framework. This works fine and runs successfully on local as well as server machine. But when I try to run the same on Jenkins, I do not get any error but Jenkins do not perform sendkeys operation.

Comment: Please provide the code of your sendkeys function

Comment: Is Jenkins running the test in headless mode or on Linux?

Comment: Code for sendkeys is as below
import SendKeys
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def send_input_keys(input):
    SendKeys.SendKeys(input)

Comment: jenkins running the test in headless mode and on windows

Answer (score 0):

instead to call your class why don't you use the robotframework send-key?
I had several problem with eternal library called from robot-framework once that I integrate them on Jenkins.

In robotFramework you can use:

```
Input Text    xpath=xpath_of_your_element    your_text
```